# Avoid message broadcast

Tags: forms, delphi, message

I am not sure how to explain this, but here goes:
I have a form with a grid with some comboboxes. From this form I create another to edit data. The edit form has also some of the comboboxes like the grid.
The values in these comboboxes can be edited from a third form.
If they are edited I send a broadcast like message to all open forms to update the comboboxes.

```
procedure HsBrodcastUpdate;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
    SendMessage(Screen.Forms[i].Handle, WM_FORMUPDATES, 0, 0);
end;
```

On each form where updates should be performed I have:

```
procedure FormUpdate(var aMessage: TMessage); message WM_FORMUPDATES;
```

This is like using a shootgun when a riffle would be enough.
It should be enough to send the message to the form where the editform was created from

I am not sure if it would give any performance boost but I would like to try.

My question: How can I instead of using HsBrodcastUpdate that sends to all forms just send the message to the form that created the form that sends the message.

Comment: You can't imagine how many messages are sent every second on a working Windows system :). Elimination of your messages will have no effect on performance.

Comment: use event like `OnEditionDone` in the editing form and create event handler in `owner` form. or just send/post message only to owner form.

Comment: ..or call the owner control perform() method

Comment: If you're wondering why no one is answering, that's because you haven't asked a question yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Class Method to Accomplish this

```
  Form1 = class(TForm1)
  ...
  private
  ...
  public
     Class procedure UpdateComboBox;
     ...
  end;
```

then the procedure looks like this

```
  class procudure TForm1.UpdateComboBox;
  var
     F: TForm2;//This is the target form
     I: Integer;
  begin
     F := nil;
     for i := Screen.FormCount - 1 DownTo 0 do
      if (Screen.Forms[i].Name = '<The Form Name Here>') then
         F := Screen.Forms[I] As TForm2;
     if F <> nil then
     begin
        //update your form's F.comboBox here
     end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a question in your post so this may not even be what you are looking for. Sounds like implementing the Observer pattern might be what you are looking for.

Here are two articles you can look at for examples, but there are plenty more out there.
http://tdelphihobbyist.blogspot.com/2009/10/observer-design-pattern-in-delphi-push.html
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/delphi

Answer (score 0):

You can build a chain of events, by exposing event handlers on your forms.
Study this example:

```
{- Main Form }

Type

TFormMain = Class(TForm)
  private
    procedure UpdateCombo( Sender : TObject);
    procedure InvokeOtherForm;
end;

TFormMain.InvokeOtherForm;
var 
  OtherForm : TOtherForm;
begin
  OtherForm := TOtherForm.Create( Nil);
  try
    OtherForm.OnUpdateCombo := Self.UpdateCombo;  // Link update event !
    OtherForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    OtherForm.Free;
  end;
end;

TFormMain.UpdateCombo( Sender : TObject);
begin
  {- Update the combos ... }
  ...
end;
```

---

```
{- OtherForm }
Type

TOtherForm = Class(TForm)
  private
    FOnUpdateCombo : TNotifyEvent;
    procedure InvokeThirdForm;
    procedure UpdateCombo( Sender : TObject);
  public
    OnUpdateCombo : TNotifyEvent read FOnUpdateCombo write FOnUpdateCombo;
  end;

TOtherForm.InvokeThirdForm;
var 
  ThirdForm : TThirdForm;
begin
  ThirdForm := TThirdForm.Create( Nil);
  try
    ThirdForm.OnUpdateCombo := Self.UpdateCombo;  // Link update event !
    ThirdForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    ThirdForm.Free;
  end;
end;

TOtherForm.UpdateCombo( Sender : TObject);
begin
  {- Do some internal updates }
  ...
  {- Pass on update information event }
  if Assigned(FOnUpdateCombo) then
    FOnUpdateCombo( Sender);
end;
```

---

```
{- ThirdForm }
Type

TThirdForm = Class(TForm)
  private
    FOnUpdateCombo : TNotifyEvent;
    procedure UpdateCombo;
  public
    OnUpdateCombo : TNotifyEvent read FOnUpdateCombo write FOnUpdateCombo;
  end;

TThirdForm.UpdateCombo;
begin
  {- Do some internal updates }
  ...
  {- Pass on update information event }
  if Assigned(FOnUpdateCombo) then
    FOnUpdateCombo( Self);
end;
```